# Check if session item exists fails itself with object reference not set error

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, session

I'm having problem regarding session items. Before I use them, I want to check if they exists, but using this codes gives me error:

```
If (Session("SomeSessionItem") Is Nothing) Then
...
End If
```

This is the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think `Session("SomeSessionItem")` tries to acquire the value of the session item. If the item doesn't exists then it throws exception. But how do I check if a session item exists before using them?

- I have a page `Home.aspx`.
- In the `Home.aspx.vb`, I instantiate a WebUserControl `SomeControl.ascx`. Note that in `Home.aspx.vb` event handler `Page_Load` I can use a condition to check session without getting an exception.
- Inside `SomeControl.ascx.vb` I'm trying to access the session, here's where the exception occurs.

Comment: Are you sure that the "Session" object is not null ?

Comment: @Ankur, session also doesnt exists! But why? I'm running it in my `ascx.vb` or webusercontrol file.

Comment: What is the control flow for the request? Is it some Ajax call or simple asp.net page life cycle?

Comment: Are you sure is shouldn't need to be `IsNot Nothing` in your case?

Comment: And: check `EnableSessionState`, if false, there is not session.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does that work for you?

```
If (Session IsNot Nothing)
    Dim item as Object = Session("SomeSessionItem")
    If (item IsNot Nothing)
    ...
    End If
End If
```

Also, you may need to check `HttpContext.Current.Session` rather than simply `Session` if you're seeing the the following error:

> Session does not exist in this context

Answer (score 5):

If you try to use sessions before the session object itself is created, you receive this behavior. Note that the Session object is not available at all times in the process of a request. You can check for Session itself to be Nothing.

It is guaranteed created *after* the [`Session_Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.start.aspx) event fired which you can check in global.asax.

In case your code runs inside the code-behind of your page, there are scenario's where the session state is not yet available. However, inside Page_Load it *is* available, check there.

Finally: when `.EnableSessionstate="false"` is set for your page or application-wide, you cannot access the session object.

---

#### Edit:

Maybe you mean instead of `If (Session("SomeSessionItem") Is Nothing) Then` the following?

```
If (Session("SomeSessionItem") IsNot Nothing) Then
    '... do someting, i.e.:'
    Dim sessionItem As String = CType(Session("SomeSessionItem"), String)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Item` on `Session`

```
If Session.Item("SomeSessionItem") Is Nothing Then
    ' No such value in session state, take appropriate action.
End If
```

Comment: `Item` is the default property, it can be called in VB.NET without Item (or did they change this in latest versions of VB?).

Comment: I would look at @Abel's answer and check if Session itself is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the error is coming from your `If` line?  What are you doing inside the `If`?

I ask because you say

> Before I use them, I want to check if they exists

and then check that they don't exist.

My guess would be that the code inside your `If` block is reading the value from `Session` and attempting to use it, right after you've checked that it doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

VB.NET

```
IF HttpContext.Current IS NOTHING Then
   ------Your Code
Else
  ----Your Code
End IF
```

C#

```
IF Session("XYZ") == NULL
{
   ---- Your Code
}
Else
{
  ---- Your Code
}
```

Comment: You should include some more details as to how or why this solves the OP's problem.  Code only answers don't provide much help in most cases.